# Server 2012 - how to make files in a folder readonly to everyone but creator/owner

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012, directory, read-only

I'd like to setup a shared folder on my Windows Server 2012 box where all the managers can put files that they can edit, and other users can open, read and print, but can't change or delete.

It would be best of only the manager who created/moved the file to the folder had access to change/delete it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](http://superuser.com/questions/745923/ntfs-permissions-create-files-and-folder-but-prevent-deletion-and-modification) something that will do what you need?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like it might work.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Making it so that each manager can edit only their own files would be complex.

I recommend just just creating a folder and making is so that the managers have modify and everyone else just has read and execute.

Comment: Here's my problem:  I don't want managers to have the ability to change/delete each other's files, and while that sounds silly, it happens.  Perhaps I should just share a folder, create subfolders with each manager's name, give that manager full rights to said folder, and everyone else just read-only rights.